# SQL AnyWhere, how do I set the database ReadOnly property to On?

Tags: sqlanywhere, permissions

Does anyone know in Sql AnyWhere, how can I set the ReadOnly property of any database to On?
I can only see the way to access the property, but cannot find the way to set it correctly at the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the read-only status of a database after it has been started. To start the database in read-only mode, use the [-r server switch](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/r-database-dbengine.html). If you're using the [`START DATABASE`](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/start-database-statement.htm) statement, you can add the `FOR READ ONLY` clause.